# With Sed how can I replace a random word without removing data on the same line

Tags: shell, unix, sed, scripting

I am trying to use sed replace a string that has a randomly generated alphanumeric. It is prefixed with a fixed word with special characters in it.

```
{abcd}RandomAlphanumric
```

I can easily replace the {abcd}, but I don't know how to replace the Random Alphanumeric without removing other words or data on the same line. I am able to accomplish exactly what I need with the following sed command, but this doesn't seem like a safe command to use in all cases. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
sed -e 's/{abcd}.........../new_myvar/g'
```

Comment: show the example of the whole line

Answer (score 1):

This will delete all strings that start with `{abcd}` followed by any number of any alphanumeric character:

```
 sed -e 's/{abcd}[[:alnum:]]*/new_myvar/g'
```

`[[:alnum:]]` matches any alphanumeric character and `[[:alnum:]]*` matches zero or more of such characters.  Because `sed` is greedy, it will match as many alphanumeric characters as possible.

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
{abcd}RandomAlphanumric
begin {abcd}adfCvr1243C end
```

Then, our output is:

```
$ sed -e 's/{abcd}[[:alnum:]]*/new_myvar/g' file
new_myvar
begin new_myvar end
```